# Add react project in solution

Tags: reactjs, xamarin, asp.net-mvc-5

I am an absolute beginner with React. My employer got a project that we are supposed to build. The project includes an android and ios apps (will be built using Xamarin native by my colleague). The project also has a web portal. I am told to learn React and build web portal. I will just get the API end-points, and I am told to consume the APIs. I am told to build a separate project in the existing solution.

Can anyone suggest me or guide me how the React web portal will fit into the whole scenario? How can I include React in the project?

I apologize for the newbie stupid question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you will be working on frontend side only right ? You can start with basics react concepts. You can learn react from youtube channels like learncodeacademy, traversymedia, thenewboston. For pulling the data from backend you can make using of `fetch()` or `axios()`.

Some useful links :

1) https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/

2) https://blog.hellojs.org/fetching-api-data-with-react-js-460fe8bbf8f2

Integrating reactjs with .NET:

1) Official docs: https://reactjs.net/

2) Tutorial: https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html

3) React-redux project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react-with-redux?view=aspnetcore-2.1

4) https://medium.com/@MaartenSikkema/using-react-redux-and-webpack-with-dotnet-core-to-build-a-modern-web-frontend-7e2d091b3ba

Comment: @Tajveer if you have any other questions please ask I will add it to my answer.

Comment: thanks for replying. I have gone through some React tutorials. Following those tutorials i made a react app using facebook's "create react app" commands. I believe that the project made by using "create-react-app" command is a node project (i m new to node ecosystem too). My question is that how i can add react (and redux) to my web pages (keeping in mind that backend of my project is going to be in ASP.NET MVC 5 built by a collegue)? thanks